# Asymptotics of VAR(p) error terms

Tags: self-study, vector-autoregression, asymptotics

Consider $VAR(p)$ process
$$y_t = A_1y_{t-1} + \dots +A_py_{t-p} + u_t$$
where $y_t$ and $u_t$ are $K\times 1$ vectors and $u_t \sim WN(0, \Sigma_u)$ is a white noise process.

The autocovariance matrices of $u_t$ are estimated as 
$$C_i = \frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=i+1}^{T}u_tu_{t-i}'$$
and autocorrelation matrices as 
$$R_i = D^{-1}C_iD^{-1}$$
$i = 0,1,\dots,h$ and $D$ is a $K\times K$ diagonal matrix, the diagonal elements being the square roots of the diagonal elements of $C_0$.

Also, define $\boldsymbol{C}_h = (C_1,\dots,C_h)$, $\boldsymbol{c}_h = vec(\boldsymbol{C}_h)$, $\boldsymbol{R}_h = (R_1,\dots,R_h)$, $\boldsymbol{r}_h = vec(\boldsymbol{R}_h)$, $R_u$ denotes the *true* correlation matrix corresponding to $\Sigma_u$.

---

In the Lutkepohl (2005) it is claimed that if $u_t$ is $K$-dimensional identically distributed white noise process, then for $h\geq 1$
$$\sqrt{T}\boldsymbol{c}_h \xrightarrow{d} N(0,I_h\otimes\Sigma_u\otimes\Sigma_u)$$
$$\sqrt{T}\boldsymbol{r}_h \xrightarrow{d} N(0,I_h\otimes R_u\otimes R_u).$$

I am having troubles in convincing myself of this result. I wanted first to figure out what is the asymptotic distribution of $\sqrt{T}vec(C_i)$ and $\sqrt{T}vec(R_i)$ with no success (in the book it claimed that the latter one distributed as $N(0, R_u\otimes R_u)$). Probably difficulty comes from the fact that I am still not comfortable with Kronecker products and vectorization operators. I fill comfortable with proving asymptotic properties for univariate processes (e.g. OLS).

Comment: I think you got your notation a bit wrong.  Please check it.

Comment: @MichaelChernick it should be fine now.

Comment: Did you really make changes? Where?

Comment: I added definitions of $D$ and $R_u$. It will be helpful if you say what you think is wrong and I check it. Now I don't see any mistakes.